# TortoiseHg how to restore entire repository from a bundle

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

My last action to rebase branches totally messed up. I saw the output message says "`saved backup bundle to xxx.hg`". Is there any way to restore entire repository from that bundle? Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

You can pull this bundle into your repo with `hg pull xxx.hg`. Afterwards you can strip the unwanted revisions with the `strip` command from the `mq` extension.

Comment: That saved me! I almost lost 3 days of work when I rebased my changeset and then accidentally destroyed the patches in my patchqueue using hgsubversion.

Answer (score 2):

You could use hg rollback to rollback the commit you just did.

http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hg.1.html#rollback

Comment: can you please provide the command? How do I specify arguments?

Comment: hg unbundle xx.hg will add back the original pre-rebased changeset, but also keep the rebased changeset. It's not like the restore I want.

Comment: Sorry, I had the wrong command at first but I just edited it to the correct one :P. My bad.

Comment: `hg rollback` won't act after a rebase. So this answer is clearly wrong.